# Recuperar dados de outro processo

Tags: c++, ponteiro, memória

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma em C++ de pegar algum dado (valor) de um processo, porém sem utilizar um ponteiro para a memória, pois, quando tento utilizar o cheat engine, até encontro o endereço dinâmico, porem o debugger não funciona para ir atrás de ponteiros.

Entao para esclarecer: Há alguma forma de obter um dado (não há a necessidade de altera-lo, apenas ler) em C++, sem a utilizaçao de ponteiros diretos?
Me disseram que isto talvez seja possivel atraves de *socket* / *hook*, isto é verdade? Existem outros métodos?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso através de sockets, arquivos(muito utilizado no UNIX), ou compartilhando o endereço de memória (mas isso já envolve ponteiros)

Comment: Sim, é verdade, mas o software tem que estar preparado para isto.

Comment: Ja que não consigo utilizar o CE para encontrar o valor estatico (ponteiro). Seria possivel criar uma forma do algoritmo procurar o endereço (dinamico) atual do processo?